# InvalidCastException on random row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a program that makes a query in the database and transform it to a xml
but im getting a InvalidCast during some rows, not  specially one ( i count the objects in XML and they vary )

```
 Banco objBanco = new Banco();


        DataTable objData;
        DataTable objFotos;
        objData = objBanco.ListaCondominio();

        XmlWriterSettings setting = new XmlWriterSettings();
        setting.Indent = true;
        XmlWriter proprietarios = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Users\STUDIO-15\Desktop\arquivocond2.xml", setting);
        // XmlWriter proprietarios = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DirectaXml\arquivo\Condominios.xml", setting);

        //CRIAÇÃO XML

        //<Imóveis>
        try { 
        proprietarios.WriteStartElement("Condominios");
        foreach (DataRow row in objData.Rows)
        {
            //<Imóvel>
            proprietarios.WriteStartElement("Condominio");
            for (int h = 0; h < row.ItemArray.Count(); h++)
            {
                //<ID COLUNA>
                proprietarios.WriteStartElement(objData.Columns[h].ToString());

                //CONTEÚDO LINHA/COLUNA
                proprietarios.WriteString(row.ItemArray[h].ToString());

                //FECHA ID COLUNA
                proprietarios.WriteEndElement();
            }
            //OBTÉM FOTOS

            objFotos = new DataTable();

            objFotos = objBanco.Fotos(Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[0]));


            proprietarios.WriteStartElement("Fotos");
            bool controlFotos = false;
            foreach (DataRow rowFotos in objFotos.Rows)
            {

                //FOTO
                proprietarios.WriteStartElement("Foto");
                //CONTEÚDO FOTO
                if (controlFotos == false)
                {
                    proprietarios.WriteString(rowFotos.ItemArray[0].ToString());
                    controlFotos = true;
                }

                else if (controlFotos == true)
                    proprietarios.WriteString(" | " + rowFotos.ItemArray[0].ToString());



                //FECHA FOTO
                proprietarios.WriteEndElement();

            }

            //FECHA FOTOS
            proprietarios.WriteEndElement();
            //FECHA IMÓVEL





            proprietarios.WriteEndElement();


        }
        //FECHA IMÓVEIS
        proprietarios.WriteEndElement();
        proprietarios.WriteEndDocument();
        proprietarios.Close();
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {

        }
```

If someone could help, i would be grateful

Comment: It should be quite easy to debug the issue, just stop debugger when an exception is thrown and then you get the exact position and the current database-values. It´s impossible from your code to guess where the exception is thrown.

Comment: its probably   
objFotos = objBanco.Fotos(Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[0]));

Comment: it is on this line, on the convert.toint32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the row.ItemArray[0] returns an int, if it returns any other characters then 0 to 9 it will not convert.

```
try{
    objFotos = objBanco.Fotos(Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[0]));
   }
catch(InvalideCastException e)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(e.message);
   }
```

Also you might want to try to .ToString() the method first.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

My database was returning 2 null rows and it was causing this exception,i could easily solve this just by adding is not null at the query